# App link verification does not work

Tags: android, deep-linking, applinks

I successfully implemented `deep-links`, but now I would love to implement `app-links` as well, but I don't get wanted results.

*AndroidManifest*

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="*.ex.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/vvv" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="ex.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/vvv" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="*.ex.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/ttt" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="ex.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/ttt" />
</intent-filter>
```

When I follow to my websites link `ex.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` I do see my .json file. I copy pasted the information in there to:

`https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator`
and it showed: `"Success! Host www.ex.com grants app deep linking to xxx."`

But still.. app links to not work.

Then I tried `https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://ex.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls`
and the response was:

`Error: unavailable: Redirect encountered while fetching statements from https://ex.com./.well-known/assetlinks.json (which is equivalent to 'https://ex.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json'): redirects are disallowed for security reasons (NOT_FOLLOWED_MAX_FORWARDS) [26] while fetching Web statements from https://ex.com./.well-known/assetlinks.json (which is equivalent to 'https://ex.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json') using download from the web (ID 1).\n********************* INFO MESSAGES *********************\n* Info: No statements were found that match your query\n",`

Where's the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There might be a typo somewhere `https://ex.com./.well-known/assetlinks.json`

Comment: No, there isn't, otherwise, it would not be possible to access my assetlinks file.

Comment: The logs contains this 'typo' unfortunately. Also, make sure your file isn't served through HTTP redirects. And finally, check the applinks from Android Studio (App links assistant)

Comment: Anyone? did you find out why this happens? I am having the same issue. No typo. when I view my page, json is there. but when i test through google, it's not there...

Comment: @MaaAn13 were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the validation url gave that error due to a redirect from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to example.com